# Carousel interval not working as expected - can't identify the issue(s)

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, carousel

I am currently working on our website's testimonials section, specifically on the testimonial carousel located in the testimonials.blade.php view.

My goal is to increase the interval time between the switches of different testimonials in the carousel. I have attempted to modify the interval time in the script, but unfortunately, my efforts have not yielded the desired result.

Here is the relevant script from the testimonials.blade.php view:

```
<section id="our-clients-section" class="z-0">
    <div id="testimonial-carousel" class="relative h-screen w-full" data-carousel="slide" style="z-index: 0">
        <div class="h-72 md:h-96 overflow-hidden bg-gray-50">
            <!-- Testimonial 1 -->
            <div class="hidden duration-700 ease-in-out" data-carousel-item>
                <section id="testimonial 1" class="bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-800">
                    <div class="max-w-screen-xl px-4 py-8 mx-auto text-center lg:py-12 lg:px-6">
                        <figure class="max-w-full mx-auto">
                            <svg class="h-12 mx-auto mb-3 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-600" viewBox="0 0 24 27" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M14.017 18L14.017 10.609C14.017 4.905 17.748 1.039 23 0L23.995 2.151C21.563 3.068 20 5.789 20 8H24V18H14.017ZM0 18V10.609C0 4.905 3.748 1.038 9 0L9.996 2.151C7.563 3.068 6 5.789 6 8H9.983L9.983 18L0 18Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                            </svg>
                            <blockquote class="testimonial-item h-56 sm:h-80 md:h-92 lg:h-56 xl:h-42 text-sm sm:text-lg md:text-lg lg:text-xl overflow-hidden">
                                <p class="font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                                    Es una buena herramienta, fácil de usar y amigable con el usuario. Cumple la función encomendada que es garantizar el cálculo de REP.
                                </p>
                            </blockquote>
                            <figcaption class="flex items-center justify-center mt-10 space-x-3">
                                <img class="w-auto h-10 md:w-auto md:h-16" src="{{ asset('images/clients/agrosuper.png') }}" alt="profile picture">
                                <div class="flex items-center divide-x-2 divide-gray-500 dark:divide-gray-700">
                                    <div class="pr-3 font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Félix Fernández Céspedes</div>
                                    <div class="pl-3 text-sm font-light text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Analista en Gestión de Datos</div>
                                </div>
                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            <!-- Testimonial 2 -->
            <div class="hidden duration-700 ease-in-out" data-carousel-item>
                <section id="testimonial 2" class="bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-800">
                    <div class="max-w-screen-xl px-4 py-8 mx-auto text-center lg:py-12 lg:px-6">
                        <figure class="max-w-full mx-auto">
                            <svg class="h-12 mx-auto mb-3 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-600" viewBox="0 0 24 27" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M14.017 18L14.017 10.609C14.017 4.905 17.748 1.039 23 0L23.995 2.151C21.563 3.068 20 5.789 20 8H24V18H14.017ZM0 18V10.609C0 4.905 3.748 1.038 9 0L9.996 2.151C7.563 3.068 6 5.789 6 8H9.983L9.983 18L0 18Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                            </svg>
                            <blockquote class="testimonial-item h-56 sm:h-80 md:h-92 lg:h-56 xl:h-42 text-sm sm:text-lg md:text-lg lg:text-xl overflow-hidden">
                                <p class="font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                                    Me ayudó a tener mayor trazabilidad de los datos cargados, ya que permite consolidar información de envases y embalajes, productos y ventas de manera estandarizada. Además, permite generar el reporte para línea base ReSimple en el formato requerido.
                                </p>
                            </blockquote>
                            <figcaption class="flex items-center justify-center mt-10 space-x-3">
                                <img class="w-auto h-10 md:w-auto md:h-16" src="{{ asset('images/clients/orizon.png') }}" alt="profile picture">
                                <div class="flex items-center divide-x-2 divide-gray-500 dark:divide-gray-700">
                                    <div class="pr-3 font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Camila Vasquez Kaid</div>
                                    <div class="pl-3 text-sm font-light text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"> Jefa de Medio Ambiente</div>
                                </div>
                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            <!-- Testimonial 3 -->
            <div class="hidden duration-700 ease-in-out" data-carousel-item>
                <section id="testimonial 3" class="bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-800">
                    <div class="max-w-screen-xl px-4 py-8 mx-auto text-center lg:py-12 lg:px-6">
                        <figure class="max-w-full mx-auto">
                            <svg class="h-12 mx-auto mb-3 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-600" viewBox="0 0 24 27" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M14.017 18L14.017 10.609C14.017 4.905 17.748 1.039 23 0L23.995 2.151C21.563 3.068 20 5.789 20 8H24V18H14.017ZM0 18V10.609C0 4.905 3.748 1.038 9 0L9.996 2.151C7.563 3.068 6 5.789 6 8H9.983L9.983 18L0 18Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                            </svg>
                            <blockquote class="testimonial-item h-56 sm:h-80 md:h-92 lg:h-56 xl:h-42 text-sm sm:text-base md:text-lg lg:text-xl overflow-hidden">
                                <p class="font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                                    La plataforma es muy útil por tres razones: 1) Facilita mucho la metodología de declaración, optimizando procesos y tiempos. 2) Ayuda a visibilizar oportunidades de ahorros económicos y aportes medioambientales, por ejemplo, cambiando materialidades o con la disminución de residuos. 3) Especialmente en el retail, tenemos muchos SKU, entonces utilizar la plataforma nos permitió hacer proyecciones de residuos para los cuales no contábamos con fichas técnicas, duplicando información semejante.
                                </p>
                            </blockquote>
                            <figcaption class="flex items-center justify-center mt-10 space-x-3">
                                <img class="w-auto h-6 md:w-auto md:h-16" src="{{ asset('images/clients/tricot.png') }}" alt="profile picture">
                                <div class="flex items-center divide-x-2 divide-gray-500 dark:divide-gray-700">
                                    <div class="pr-3 font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Antonio Barreda Hernández</div>
                                    <div class="pl-3 text-sm font-light text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"> Jefe de Sostenibilidad</div>
                                </div>
                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            <!-- Testimonial 4 -->
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I have attempted to raise the interval time, but the changes do not seem to take effect. Could you please review the provided script and provide guidance on how I can successfully increase the interval time between testimonial switches?

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const testimonialCarousel = document.getElementById('testimonial-carousel');
        const testimonialItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-carousel-item]'));
        const options = {
            interval: 3000,
            onChange: function () {
            },
        };
        const carousel = new Carousel(testimonialCarousel, testimonialItems, options);

        function autoSwitchTestimonials() {
            setInterval(() => {
                carousel.next();
            }, options.interval);
        }
        autoSwitchTestimonials();
    });
</script>
```

I'm trying to raise the `interval` time with no success... Would you please give me a hint of the issue?

Comment: The logic in your code seems to be right, try putting `console.logs` to track the changes. The error should be something else.

Comment: So, everything is working, but you are not able to change the time? Have you tried it dumping browser cache? To quickly test it uncached, try it in a Private Window.

Comment: @Kalnode exactly. I've cleared cache and views. Also tried reloading composer, re running npm run dev and using a Private Window.